# python UnicodeEncodeError when use python2 with `from __future__ import unicode_literals`

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to write code compatible with python2 and python3.
I need `from __future__ import unicode_literals`, so how can I print unicode string?

file: hello.py

```
# encoding=utf-8
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals
print("你好")
```

python2 hello.py

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 2-13: ordinal not in range(128)
```

python3 hello.py

```
你好
```

Comment: You've only solved half the problem - `unicode_literals` allows you to put Unicode characters into your program. The error is now generated by `print` itself because the encoding for output is set to `ascii`.

Answer (score -1):

You should set the encoding of your script with the `# -*- coding: <encoding name> -*-` header:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals
print("你好")
```

Please refer to [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/#defining-the-encoding) for details.

Comment: if that were the case, OP would have gotten `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe4' in file hello.py on line 3, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details`.  What I suspected doesn't seem to match the error message either: `LANG= python hello.py`: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)`... something is off here...